# case condition on join statement with two different join conditions in SQL RedShift

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, join, conditional-statements

I have requirement that  the cloumn value of name and id should return null in case of "b.end_dt < c.report_mnth"(less than) else "b.end_dt > c.report_mnth"(greater than) then column should show the value  .  I cant able to achieve this in a single query  . I am trying this Amazon Redshift database . I have tried with some case condition but still I couldn't achieve this

As of now I have prepared a query that returns name and id as null in case of "b.end_dt < c.report_mnth"(less than)

**Query which I have tried**

```
SELECT null as name, null as id, b.strt_dt, b.end_dt from demo.v a  
LEFT JOIN demo.emp_pos b on (a.pos_sk1=b.pos_sk and a.pos_id1=b.pos_id)  
JOIN demo.load_status c on b.end_dt < c.report_mnth
```

Please help to solve this or at least need a clue to complete this. 
Thanks in advance

**Expected output**

```
name        id      strt_dt     end_dt
                    2015-04-12  2016-04-18
                    2015-04-12  2016-04-18
                    2015-04-12  2016-04-18
                    2015-04-12  2016-04-18
                    2015-04-12  2016-04-18
                    2015-04-12  2016-04-18
                    2016-02-02  2016-03-08
                    2016-02-02  2016-03-08
                    2016-02-02  2016-03-08
                    2016-02-02  2016-03-08
john ma     abc12   2014-11-30  9999-12-31
john ma     abc12   2014-11-30  9999-12-31
john ma     abc12   2014-11-30  9999-12-31
john ma     abc12   2014-11-30  9999-12-31
john ma     abc12   2014-11-30  9999-12-31
john ma     abc12   2014-11-30  9999-12-31
john ma     abc12   2014-11-30  9999-12-31
john ma     abc12   2014-11-30  9999-12-31
john ma     abc12   2014-11-30  9999-12-31
john ma     abc12   2014-11-30  9999-12-31
```

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result - as formatted text.

Comment: Provide some data of your tables

Answer (score 1):

Please let me know whether my answer is correct actually I have prepared two select query with the join condition  like 1st query is to check less than i.e "b.end_dt < c.report_mnth"  and return null value for 2 columns(name ,id) and 2nd query is to check the greater than i.e b.end_dt > c.report_mnth and return actual values  for those 2 columns (name ,id) . I achieved this "UNION ALL"

Query

```
SELECT null as name,null as id, b.strt_dt,b.end_dt from demo.v a  LEFT JOIN demo.emp_pos b on 
( a.pos_sk1=b.pos_sk and a.pos_id1=b.pos_id)  JOIN    demo.load_status c   on 
b.end_dt < c.report_mnth 

UNION ALL

SELECT null as name,null as id, b.strt_dt,b.end_dt from demo.v a  LEFT JOIN demo.emp_pos b on 
( a.pos_sk1=b.pos_sk and a.pos_id1=b.pos_id)  JOIN    demo.load_status c   on 
b.end_dt > c.report_mnth
```

I think I got my expected output.

Thanks guys

Comment: note that you keep duplicates with "union all" - if duplicate rows should be removed, use "duplicate" only. See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_example_unionall_query.html